# $S_{n} = <(1,2),(2,3),....,(n-1,n)>$ proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

$S_{n} = <(1,2),(2,3),....,(n-1,n)>$ I have to proof this problem.

I tried to find it online, but no succes so far, any tips/solves or links to something relevant would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Here's some intuition: you can gradually change the word DCEBA to ABCDE, where in each step you swap two neighboring letters (DCEBA -> DCBEA -> DCBAE -> .... -> ABCDE). This is called "bubble sort". If you write down the steps, you will get a decomposition of the permutation to transpositions of neighboring positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This is obviously true for $n = 2$. Assume $n >2$ and result known for $n-1$. Then by induction, $S_{n-1} = \langle (1,2),(2,3), \ldots ,(n-2,n-1) \rangle$. Now show that $\langle (1,2),(2,3), \ldots (n-1,n) \rangle$ contains $(1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n)$.

Comment: well if we assume that $S_{n-1}$ is true, then $S_{n} = ⟨S_{n-1}(n-1,n)⟩$ while $S_{n-1}$ is true, then it equals that $S_{n}$ is true, right ? Is that a correct and complete demonstration ?

Comment: Yes, if you can show that $S_{n} = \langle S_{n-1}, (n-1,n) \rangle$, then you are done by induction. But there is something to be done.  My idea was to use the fact that $| \langle (1,2,3,4,5, \ldots,n-1,n)\rangle | |S_{n-1}| = |S_{n}|$, but there are other ways to show it.

Comment: But how $|⟨(1,2,3,4,5,…,n−1,n)⟩||S_{n−1}|=|S_{n}|$ ? $|⟨(1,2,3,4,5,…,n−1,n)⟩|$ is $n!$ and $|S_{n-1}|$ is $(n-1)!$, and how can $n! * (n-1)! = n!$ ? ... maybe I'm missing something

Comment: You are missing something. The $n$-cycle $(1,2,\ldots,n-1,n)$ generates a cyclic group of order $n$ which intersects $S_{n-1}$ in the identity only. Then use the formula $|AB| = |A||B|/|A \cap B|$ when $A$ and $B$ are subgroups.

Comment: so $|S_{n}*S_{n-1}| = |S_{n}|*|S_{n-1}|/|S_{n}∩S_{n-1}|$ which equals to $(n! * (n-1)!)/{(n-1)!} = n!$ which is $S_{n}$, is that correct?

Comment: It is correct as far as it goes, but it is not what I intended. You have $A$ cyclic of order $n$, $B$ of order $(n-1)!$ and $A \cap B$ of order $1$. So $|AB| = n(n-1)!/1 = n!$ and $AB$ must be all of $S_{n}$.

Comment: I see, I think I understand now, so if $B$ would have been of order $(n-2)!$, then the order of $A$ would have been $n(n-1)$, right ?

Comment: Got automatic message to limit discussion, but no, not quite right. It would be true if you had subgroups $X$ and $Y$ with $X$ of order $n$ and $Y$ of order $(n-1)!$ and $X \cap Y$ of order $(n-2)!$, then you would have $|XY| = n(n-1)$.

Comment: I got this problem on my exam, the next day after I posted this, and I passed it, thanks for the help man :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you-I hope you will remember the solution next time you see that question!

Answer (score 1):

I think you know that $S_n$ is generated by transpositions, so we just need to show that we can get to $(a,b)$. Since the set of generators has a cyclical simmetry, we just need to prove that we can obtain $(1,a)$ for $a=1,\dots, n$.

Now just notice that $$(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)=(1,3),$$ $$(1,3)(3,4)(1,3)=(1,4),$$ $$(1,4)(4,5)(1,4)=(1,5),$$ and so on.